How can I sync VS Code code changes with UndertaleModTool file?
I was wondering if you can use UTMT \w VSCode, this so i can keep my changes more synced between my VSCode code and the UTMT code, it is also helpful for version control.
So, is there any way to do this? Any extension for VSCode? Any API to easily send changes from VSCode to a data.win file?

What source-control are you currently using? Please explain how you use both VSC and UTMT together and what kinds of data/files/state is shared and what is exclusive - that way we can try to understand the situation and offer appropriate advice.

So, I have a pizza tower mod and I added some objects to the data.win file, in VSCode I have a folder that contains the object name and the scripts acording to the event of the object and i have my VSCode folder synced with github for version control.

UTMT has support for scripts for automation.
I do not know whether there is an existing solution for the described use case, but at the very least there were a handful of scripts to export scripts to a project file, which you might be able to use as reference.

How do I use it tho, I know nothing about C# and there is next to no documentation...

As far as I'm aware, that's the only option at the moment - judge for yourself if the added effort of learning some C# and looking at the comments in code is worth the time it'll save you.
